# Kill a NextJs process in terminal

Tags: node.js, bash, next.js, terminal

I used to be able to kill a NextJs process with `killall -9 node`. Since the most recent nextJS update this no longer works. I can see this with `lsof -i :3000`.

How can I kill my NextJS process?

Answer (score 0):

You can now kill a NextJS process with:

```
killall -9 next-server
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running NextJs using `npm`, you can do.

```
pkill npm
```

or fetch the npm process id and use `kill`

```
ps -all | grep npm
0 S  1000 1405515  141857  3  80   0 - 282002 do_epo pts/13  00:00:00 npm run dev

kill 1405515
```

For more information read `man kill` or `man pkill`